# Mongo: $push is not working with array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a piece of python code using pymongo. It checks in the collection if there's already a document present with 'sn'=sn. If yes, then update ("$push" date and sn_ch values to "owner" array, else create a new document. When I run this, I don't see any error, but the array doesn't get updated..

```
    Module = {'sn':sn,'descr':descr,'owners':[{'date':date,'sn_ch':sn_ch}],'name':name}
    myCur = db.modules.find({'sn':sn}).count()
    print(myCur)
    if myCur >                 
            db.mobules.update({'sn':sn}, {'$push': {'owners':{'date':date,'sn_ch':sn_ch}}})
    else:
            db.modules.insert(Module)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to push an object to the array or want to replace the array itself?

Comment: Hope you have read [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#definition) already before using it. The way you wrote the query, it will push the array inside 'owners' array. That is what you want to do?

Comment: hi, sorry for the mistake. I want to push an element in the array. Edited the "update" instruction.

Comment: considering typo error on this line if myCur >                 
            db.mobules.update ==> should be modules

Comment: It should work fine except the typo `mobules`. Is it the mistake you did in your code too?

Comment: Hi aro - it would be useful if you posted the document you're expecting to update, in the modules/mobules collection.